# laravel collections->keyBy finds similar keys

Tags: php, laravel, collections

laravel 5.5
here is the collections:

`$collections = collect(['name' => 'Rob'], ['nickname' => 'Robby']);`

the both methods:

```
$collections->keyBy('name')
$collections->keyBy('nickname')
```

return equil result

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "" => "Rob"
  ]
}
```

as me this looks like wrong...

Comment: What is the data Structure Do You Expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your collection is not well formatted, do it like this:

```
$collections = collect([ //main collection array
            [ 'name' => 'Rob1', 'nickname' => 'Robby1' ] //object 0 inside collection array with well formated keys => values
        ]);
```

Now when you use:

```
$collections->keyBy('name')
$collections->keyBy('nickname')
```

It will work as spected

Comment: got it... my bad I thought keyBy is searching collection by key. But keyBy just replace index within (key)

Answer (score 1):

I Think You Should pass one parameter as an array .. Try This

```
$collections = collect([['name' => 'Rob'], ['nickname' => 'Robby']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

so results are

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Rob" => array:1 [▼
      "name" => "Rob"
    ]
    "" => array:1 [▼
      "nickname" => "Robby"
    ]
  ]
}
```

and

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "" => array:1 [▼
      "name" => "Rob"
    ]
    "Robby" => array:1 [▼
      "nickname" => "Robby"
    ]
  ]
}
```

still looks invalid searching in collections...
and

`$collections->keyBy('nick')`

returns

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "" => array:1 [▼
      "nickname" => "Robby"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: all three keyBy are not empty, even last